# Not like in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have to select data from database using LINQ to SQL. There is a condition that i should select only record with ID **not** containing "0000" at begin ( whole ID number have six digits).

For example when I would want to select data starting with "0000" I will use:

```
var idList = (from s
    in db.TABLE
    where s.ID.StartsWith("0000")
    select s.ID
    );
```

but I need to use method more like `NotStartsWith` or `NotContains` instead of `StartsWith`. Is that possible?

Comment: Bah it was so obvious. Shame on me ;(. In meanwhile I did something like: `Func<string, bool> selctor = str => !str.StartsWith("0000");` and added this delegate in `.Where(selctor);` at the end of this LINQ query. But ofc negate is much simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `!s.ID.StartsWith("0000")`? (i.e. using the [negation operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2.aspx) `!`)

Answer (score 3):

```
var idList = (from s
    in db.TABLE
    where !s.ID.StartsWith("0000")
    select s.ID
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Startswith returns an boolean value. So you can simply negate the StartsWith. Your query should be like below;

```
var idList = (from s
    in db.TABLE
    where !s.ID.StartsWith("0000")
    select s.ID
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Of Course.. just add a logical negation operator (!) in front of the StartsWith statetment:

!s.ID.StartsWith("0000")

Answer (score 0):

Heres a handy extension method

```
public static class StringExtenstionMethods
{
    public static bool DoesNotStartWith(this string source,string target)
    {
        return !source.StartsWith(target);
    }
}


var idList = (from s      
in db.TABLE      
where s.ID.DoesNotStartWith("0000")      
select s.ID);
```